# Filter a string based on binary sequence using itertools.compress

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a string and binary sequence(which is int of 0s and 1s)

```
sent1 = 'ERAGSJKDLLDERRR'
bin_seq = 100101010100011
```

So I want to fetch the letters by comparing with `bin_seq`. So it will return the letter if the value of `bin_seq` is 1 at corresponding positions.

So it should return:

```
'EGJDLRR'
```

I am using `itertools.compress` for the above operation.

```
from itertools import compress

sent1 = 'ERAGSJKDLLDERRR'
bin_seq = 100101010100011

print("".join(list(itertools.compress(sent1, str(bin_seq)))))
```

Which returns the output:

```
'ERAGSJKDLLDERRR'
```

I know I can do it easily by using `for` loop:

```
sent_new = []
for i,j in zip(sent1, str(bin_seq)):
    if j == '1':
        sent_new.append(i)
print("".join(sent_new))
```

*But I am more concern about why it is not giving expected output with `itertools.compress`.*

Comment: You could also `compress` (pun intended) your `zip` approach in a single line: `"".join(c for c, b in zip(sent1, str(bin_seq)) if b == '1')`

Comment: @tobias_k I am practicing with `itertools` so I was more concern about `itertool.compress` solution.

Comment: BTW, IMHO using an `int` for `bin_seq` is not a good choice. You should only use numeric types if you intend to do math, e.g. not for phone numbers, zip codes, or other strings that just happen to be all-numbers.

Comment: You caused the problem by trying to pass in bin_seq = 100101010100011, which makes it an integer, not a binary sequence (or even a string). The problem then becomes how to convert it back to a sequence (or iterable) of binary digits. So the question title is a misnomer: your "binary sequence" stopped being a binary sequence the moment you converted it to integer, which makes tthings harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `compress` approach is close. It's not working because the strings "0" and "1" both evaluate to True in a boolean context. One quick solution is to convert them to ints, since 0 is False and 1 is True in a boolean context:

```
import itertools

sent1 = 'ERAGSJKDLLDERRR'
bin_seq = 100101010100011

print("".join(itertools.compress(sent1, map(int, str(bin_seq)))))
```

Result:

```
EGJDLRR
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import compress

''.join(compress(sent1, map(int, str(bin_seq))))

'EGJDLRR'
```

The issue is you need to feed `compress` a list of (0, 1) as ints.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LC instead of for loop

```
''.join([c for c, b in zip(sent1, str(bin_seq)) if b=='1'])
```

---

Edit:
For the sake of interest I timed the two by now available solutions:

```
''.join(compress(sent1, map(int, str(bin_seq))))
1.360 s                                                    
''.join([c for c, b in zip(sent1, str(bin_seq)) if b=='1']) 
0.766 s
```